# Android: XML Parsing problem

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Im able to pasre and display the xml in this [page](http://utvmoney.mangopeople.com/apps/butv/gainers-losers/nse) using the following method..

```
private void loadTopMoversData() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML(TOPMOVERS_XML);
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("scrip");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {       
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
            map.put("name", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
            map.put("currprice", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "currprice"));
            map.put("percentage", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "percentage"));
            map.put("code", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "code"));
            mylist.add(map);

            Log.i("tag", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "headline") + " " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "time") );
        }
    }
```

But Im unable to parse the xml in this [page](http://feeds.utvmoney.mangopeople.com/news-home-summary) using the same method, but with appropriate tags. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void loadNewsData() {
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {

        String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML(NEWS_XML);
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("data");
        ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {   
            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            map.put("headline", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "headline"));
            map.put("link", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "link"));
            map.put("time", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "time"));
            links.add(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "link"));
            mylist.add(map);            

            Log.i("tag", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "headline") + " " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "time") );
        }   

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }   
}`
```

This is my XmlFunctions.java

```
public class XMLfunctions {

public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

    Document doc = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is); 

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc;

}

 public final static String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node kid;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return kid.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 public static String getXML(String webURL){     
        String line = null;

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(webURL);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        }

        return line;

}

public static int numResults(Document doc){     
    Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();
    int res = -1;

    try{
        res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());
    }catch(Exception e ){
        res = -1;
    }

    return res;
}

public static String getValue(Element item, String str) {       
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
    return XMLfunctions.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}
}
```

Has it something to do with the xml file? Please help. Thanks

**EDIT:**
Can someone please also tell me how to parse XML with '&' in it with this parser?

Comment: What error are you getting while parsing second document?

Comment: Can I just say eww to the way that you are parsing XML and can I suggest that you use an annotation based parser like Simple. I even wrote a blog post on how to use it here: http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. In the XMLfunctions.java, it check if the node is a TEXT_NODE and apparently the node in the xml is not one..

```
if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                 return kid.getNodeValue();
}
```

So, I removed the condition, and it works correctly now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to recheck your xml node names, case sensitive. Also check you link array is that function properly?

Answer (score 0):

The second feed is not proper XML.  As you thought `&` is not properly escaped.  It needs to be like this: `&amp;`  see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Characters_and_escaping).

However, some parsers are tolerant of this and will not error out.  Your parser is not one if these.

You could either try a few different parsers or you could try to fix the feed with a find a replace before you start parsing.  If you do this, you will have to be careful not to re-escape characters that have already been escaped, otherwise you will end up with something like this: `&amp;amp;`